# exception when starting google map

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-maps

I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyBc5VI2J_l9cLb1J4pfCXoWxg74xorbpS0"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when i run my app , i got the exception:

```
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.williamroma.example/com.williamroma.example.GoogleMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.williamroma.example.GoogleMapActivity.onCreate(GoogleMapActivity.java:11)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  ... 11 more
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.maps.MapView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.williamroma.example-1.apk]
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
03-29 12:20:12.555: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  ... 20 more
03-29 12:20:14.754: I/Process(279): Sending signal. PID: 279 SIG: 9
```

I don't know if that key is the right key, maybe you know if it looks like good,
what is that? how to solve it please?, thanks in advance. maybe the wrong is in another code, i can give me any code u want, my app is just on activity,

#### java code

```
package com.williamroma.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GoogleMapActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

#### mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.williamroma.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.williamroma.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.williamroma.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="permission_name" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GoogleMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBc5VI2J_l9cLb1J4pfCXoWxg74xorbpS0" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

#### when i add this code

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

i got this exception in the console and the app not even started :(

```
[2013-03-29 05:38:40 - GoogleMap] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2013-03-29 05:38:40 - GoogleMap] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-03-29 05:38:40 - GoogleMap] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: add this in to ur mainfest        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> inside application tag

Comment: when i add ur code i got `[2013-03-29 05:33:04 - GoogleMap] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2013-03-29 05:33:04 - GoogleMap] Please check logcat output for more details.`

Comment: @selva please help :( :(

Comment: @user2223727 check the answer hope it will work for you!!

Answer (score 0):

Create AVD with google 2.2 sdk and run your app and make sure that you're using MapActvity.

Because normal activity, will not work for mapview.